# How can I retrieve items from a bounded buffer in the order they were originally produced in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have fairly typical producer/consumer problem which I have solved with a [bounded buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  A single process generates items and hands them off to N worker threads.  The worker threads process those items and place the results in a bounded buffer.  A final consumer process retrieves the finished items from the buffer.  The following data flow diagram illustrates:

[image]

Each worker takes a variable amount of time to process its item, so the workers insert finished items into the bounded buffer in essentially random order.  This works well enough, but it is sometimes necessary to retrieve the finished items in the *same* order they were originally generated.  So the question is:

**How can I modify my existing implementation to retrieve finished items in order?**

An important additional constraint is that we must respect the size of the bounded buffer.  If the buffer has size M, then we can't have more than M finished items waiting for the consumer at any given time.

**Bounded Buffer**

The bounded buffer has a straightforward interface:

```
template <class T> class bounded_buffer
{
public:
  // initializes a new buffer
  explicit bounded_buffer(size_t capacity);
  // pushes an item into the buffer, blocks if full
  void push(T item);
  // pops an item from the buffer, blocks if empty
  T pop();
};
```

**Processing an Item**

The worker threads use the following code to process an item:

```
std::unique_lock guard{ source_lock };
auto item = GetNextItem();
guard.unlock();

buffer.push(ProcessItem(std::move(item)));
```

(The actual code is quite a bit more complex since it must handle the end of the input data, cancellation, and processing errors.  But these details are not relevant to the question.)

The code for retrieving a finished item simply pops the bounded buffer:

```
auto processed_item = buffer.pop();
```

Comment: A simple approach would be to assign each work-item (and its result) a unique ID, using an incrementing counter.  Then if a consumer needs to process a set of work-item-results in the same order they were generated, it can gather the necessary results together into a key/value data structure (e.g. a `std::map<>`), and then when it has all of the results it needs, iterate over that set (in ascending-key-order) to process the results.

Comment: That certainly works (though a partially sorted vector is probably a better choice for the secondary queue).  The problem is that this violates my constraint that we must not queue more items than allowed by the bounded buffer.  Imagine the case where we must process N items, but processing the first item takes longer than all other items combined.  Our secondary queue ends up storing N - 1 items, regardless of the bounded buffer size.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps you can address that issue by limiting the amount of parallelism in your second stage, at least during processing where you need to consume results in-order?  i.e. if you have 8 cores on your machine, you probably don't benefit from having more than 8 worker-processes, and therefore you could just issue work-items no more than 8 at a time (then hold off issuing more until all 8 are done), and therefore never have to buffer more than 8 results at a time.

Comment: That could also work, but I suspect it would be less efficient since we would have to wait for the long poll before starting each batch of 8.  In any case, if you have some ideas on how to approach this problem, please feel free to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will present two solutions.  The first is quick and simple.  The second builds on the idea behind the first to yield something a little more efficient.

**First Approach: std::future**

The basic idea is that we will "reserve" a space in the bounded buffer when we first retrieve a value and fill it in when we finish processing the item.  `std::future` provides a ready made mechanism to accomplish this.  Instead of using a `bounded_buffer<T>`, we will use a `bounded_buffer<std::future<T>>`.  We tweak the worker code as follows:

```
std::unique_lock guard{ source_lock };
auto item = GetNextItem();    
std::promise<T> processed_item;
buffer.push(processed_item.get_future());
guard.unlock();

processed_item.set_value(ProcessItem(std::move(item)));
```

We then tweak the consumer code just a touch to retrieve the value from the future:

```
auto processed_item = buffer.pop().get();
```

If the consumer process retrieves an item before a worker has finished with it, then `std::future<T>::get` will ensure that the consumer blocks until the item is ready.

Pros:

- Relatively straightforward, and it solves the problem.  We place futures into the bounded buffer while holding the source lock, so this guarantees that the final results enter the buffer in the same order we retrieved them from the source.
- Doesn't require any changes to the bounded buffer itself, preserving the purity of that abstraction.

Cons:

- `std::future` is relatively heavy-weight, requiring additional memory allocations and internal synchronization.
- We now hold the source lock while we push into the buffer (and pushing may block); this is probably fine but potentially problematic if `GetNextItem()` is expensive.

**Second Approach: Build a Better Buffer**

To address the performance concerns in the first approach, we can tweak the bounded buffer implementation to build the idea of reserving a space into it.  We will make three changes to its interface:

1. Change the constructor to accept a predicate.
2. Change the push method to return a locator.
3. Add a new `replace` method that accepts a locator and a value.

The modified interface is as follows:

```
template <class T, class P> class bounded_buffer
{
public:
  using locator_type = /* unspecified */;
  // initializes a new buffer; an item is "available" if and only if it
  // satisfies this predicate
  explicit bounded_buffer(size_t capacity, P predicate);
  // pushes an item into the buffer, blocks if full; the buffer's count of
  // available items will increase by one if and only if all items in the
  // buffer (including the new one) are available
  locator_type push(T item);
  // pops an item from the buffer, blocks if empty
  T pop();
  // replaces an existing item in the buffer; if the item is the first in the
  // buffer, then we set the count of available items as follows: 0 if the
  // item is unavailable, or X if it is available where X is the number of 
  // available items at the front of the buffer
  void replace(locator_type location, T item);
};
```

We then change the type stored in the bounded buffer from `T` to `std::variant<std::monostate, T>`.  The predicate will consider an item "available" if it contains a T.  We change the worker code as follows:

```
std::unique_lock guard{ source_lock };
auto item = GetNextItem();      
auto location = buffer.push(std::monostate{});
guard.unlock();

buffer.replace(location, ProcessItem(std::move(item));
```

The retrieval code in the consumer must also change in order to retrieve the value from the variant:

```
auto processed_item = std::get<1>(buffer.pop());
```

Pros:

- Lighter-weight and consequently more performant than the `std::future` approach.  (It requires only slightly more memory than the original version to store the `std::variant` indicies.)
- Solves the problem in basically the same way as the `future` version.

Cons:

- Requires changes to the bounded buffer implementation, and its basis operations are no longer quite what you'd expect for this abstraction.
- Does not address the source lock issue identified above.

**Error Handling**

I've omitted error handling for simplicity.  Nevertheless proper exception handling is required for both approaches.  If an exception occurs while processing an item with the code as written, the consumer will hang because it will wait for a reserved item that will never arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposal:

1. Add to the `WorkItem` class a "requires" field.  This field will be of type `shared_ptr<WorkItem>` (or similar).  If non-NULL, this field indicates a dependency between the two `WorkItem`s -- for example, if the requires-field of `WorkItem` B is set to point to `WorkItem` A, that means that the consumer process needs to consume `A` before `B`.
2. Also add to each `WorkItem` a `condition variable` (and its associated `mutex`)
3. Also add to each `WorkItem` a boolean "consumed" field.  This field will default to `false`, however, when the consumer process consumes the `WorkItem`, it will lock the `WorkItem`'s `mutex`, set this field to `true`, call `notify_all()` on the `WorkItem`'s `condition variable`, and then unlock the `mutex`.
4. When a worker-process is done processing a `WorkItem`, it must check the "requires" field of the `WorkItem`.  If the "requires" field is `NULL`, the `WorkItem` may be added to the bounded-queue immediately, and the worker-process's job is done.
5. Otherwise, the worker-process must lock the `mutex` of the "requires" field's `WorkItem` and check its "consumed" variable -- if it's set to `true` , the worker-process should unlock the `mutex` and enqueue the referencing `WorkItem`, and it's job is done.
6. If we got here, then the worker-process can't enqueue its `WorkItem` yet because its `WorkItem` has an ordering dependency that prevents it.  So in this case, the worker-process should call `wait()` on the `condition variable` of its dependency.  That will put the worker-process to sleep until its "requires"-`WorkItem` has been consumed -- at which point the worker-process will wake up (via the `notify_all()` call in step 3) and can enqueue its own `WorkItem` as usual.

That logic should be sufficient to ensure the correct ordering when specified, while still allowing worker-processes to work as efficiently as possible on `WorkItems` that don't have consumption-ordering requirements.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Thanks for sharing.